# Client stuck while printing strings using stream and lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, stream, client

On server side I have:

```
bookDataCollection.forEach((isbnL, bookDataL) -> outputCharToNetwork.println(bookDataL.getTitle()));
```

which sends string(s) to client.
I tested it and works well. All string(s) from collection I wanted are sent to client.

On client side I have:

```
inputCharFromNetwork.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
```

And this makes me problems. I got list of all book titles I sent from server, as this one:

> Don Quixote
>   2001: A Space Odyssey
>   The Hobbit

**with cursor in new line and stuck client** waiting for something as far as I can see.
What is the correct line on client side?

ADD:
`inputCharNetwork` and `outputCharNetwork` are defined as follows:

```
    BufferedReader inputCharNetwork = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter outputCharNetwork = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
```

Comment: So `lines()` is waiting for another line; how is it told that the list is complete?

Comment: I suppose that could be problem.  
I suppose that server should send some notification that data sending is over.

Comment: Acctualy, streams should work in this way: `lines()` is reading while it has something (lazy operation), after that terminating operation is executing  - in this case `forEach()` - finishing the line.

Comment: Well what do you expect to happen? You read all the lines and printed them.

Comment: I expect for client program to go on, on next line of code ... sure ...

Comment: @Luka `lines()` could be an iterator, executing the forEach on each line, rather than first reading all the lines, and then calling forEach on each of them. You could do a ` outputCharToNetwork.println("done") ` after the server-side statement, and besides printing `done` client side, it would still wait, until the connection is broken.

Comment: @Kenney That's not true as far as I understand from here: [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--)  
I didn't understand your idea at the end.

Comment: Thanks for referencing the docs!  It appears your code should work as you expect, so the problem might be outside of what you pasted. How are `outputCharToNetwork` and `inputCharToNetwork` defined? Could you provide a minimal working code example to help reproduce the problem? Say, hardcoded to localhost:someport and only sending "one", "two"?

Comment: I have no idea where "outside" should I look for a problem. I put ADD in question for clarification.
It will be easier for me to put whole program on Google Drive and you can try it. It's not so big.

Comment: That’s all as it is supposed to work. `lines().forEach(…)` means “process *all* lines”, not “stop after some unspecified idle time”. As long as the stream has not reached its end, and in case of network connections, “end” means “has been closed”, `forEach` will wait for more lines.

Comment: @Holger
Thank you for your answer and interest. 
I thougth it is working in this way: after server-side line I put here have sent all strings it sent some 'end notion' also.
"in case of network connections, “end” means “has been closed”" is part I missing. :-)  
Would you find some docs reference for this, please? It can be helpful for related things.

Comment: @Holger Would you like to put this as answer to this question? Not because of me, but others. It would be more appropriate than I "answering" my question.